# How to set target="_blank" for links in CKEditor

Tags: 8, navigation, wysiwyg

I use CKEditor in Drupal 8.
I want that every link will open in a new tab of browser. I want that the code look like this

```
    <a href="#" target="_blank">my link</a>
```

But if I use the link Button in editor I do not have choice for target blank. I only can fill in the url of link and the code looks like this

```
    <a href="#">my link</a>
```

Any idea what I have to do for changing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### [D8 Editor Advanced link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link) module

> Enhances the link Dialog in D8 CKEditor. Allows to define the
>   following attributes:
>
> - title
> - class
> - id target
> - rel

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Linkit module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit) and add a "target" attribute at admin/config/content/linkit/manage/default/attributes/add

It has two options:

- Selectlist with predefined targets.

[image: Dialog with options]

- Simple checkbox to allow links to be opened in a new browser window or tab.

[image: Dialog with checkbox]

Comment: I prefer Linkit because it provides an easy interface for internal linking with wysiwyg editors by using an autocomplete field.

Comment: Linkit 8.x-5.x has removed support for link attributes. The module's page advises: "If you are in need for link attributes, please see D8 Editor Advanced link", as posted in chosen solution here.

Answer (score 5):

If you want *every* link to open in a new window, it'd be better to not use the Editor Advanced Link module, but instead add a filter to your text format that sets `target=_blank` on every `<a>`.

Comment: How can I do that: "add a filter to your text format that sets target=_blank on every <a>"? I don't see that kind of filter when edit a text format.

Comment: You'd have to create one. Unless https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink already does this, it sounds like it might.